# jQuery animation won't work after click

Tags: jquery, css, button, jquery-animate

```
<script>

    var swidth = $(window).width();
    var sheight = $(window).height();

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#box").animate({    //animates depending on screen size

            top: (sheight*0.22)+"px",
            left: (swidth*0.25)+"px",
            width:(swidth*0.3)-40+"px",
            height: (sheight*0.35)-40+"px",

        }, 2000, function(){

            $('<input type="button" value="My button">').appendTo(this)
            .click(function(){ 

                $(this).animate({  // reverses animation back to original size and location


                top: "150px",
                left: "100px",
                width:"1px",
                height: "1px",

                }, 2000, )

            });
        });


    });

</script>
```

If I replace...

```
            $(this).animate({  // reverses animation back to original size and location


            top: "150px",
            left: "100px",
            width:"1px",
            height: "1px",

            }, 2000, )
```

...with...

```
alert("You clicked me!");
```

...it works. So the error is in the reverse animation somewhere. But where? Thanks for any answers in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 2 problems here

1. A syntax problem of extra ,
2. You are animating the wrong element, in the click handler registered to the button `this` points to the clicked button but you need to animate the `#box` element which is the parent element of the button

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").animate({
        top: (sheight*0.22)+"px",
        left: (swidth*0.25)+"px",
        width:(swidth*0.3)-40+"px",
        height: (sheight*0.35)-40+"px",
    }, 2000, function(){
        $('<input type="button" value="My button">').appendTo(this).click(function(){ 
            $(this).parent().animate({ //you need to animate the parent element #box, here this is the button you clicked
                top: "150px",
                left: "100px",
                width:"1px",
                height: "1px",
            }, 2000 ) //additional , here

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked perfectly. I see what you mean. I tried replacing 'this' with '"#box"' and the code didn't work, do you know why? Would '(this).parent()' not be the same as '("#box")'?

Comment: @DennisCallanan it should work `$('#box')` instead of `$(this).parent()`

Comment: Hmm.. it actually works now. I find that really weird. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a rogue **","** in your `animate` method. You'd be getting this error right now if you check your console right now :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Change:

```
}, 2000, ) //last line of the animate method
```

to

```
}, 2000)
```

and

```
height: "1px",
```

to

```
height: "1px"
```

And if you are trying to make the element with id `box` to animate back, you'd be better off keeping your `click` out of `animate`, like this :

```
$("#box").on("click", "input[type=button]", function () {
    $(this).parent("#box").animate({ //use parent
        top: "150px",
        left: "100px",
        width: "1px",
        height: "1px"
    }, 2000);
});
```

Then, in the callback,

```
$('<input type="button" value="My button">').appendTo(this);
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually had it right originally but changed it thinking that it may have been the problem

Comment: hmmm..also you need to use `parent()` to make it work for `#box`